# add multilevel caption in figures

Tags: floats, subfloats

I am working on overleaf, i need to place images caption like this (highlighted with red pen and blue pen in figure below) separate caption for every image then one caption for two images. The code is given below  this code only place captions for two separate images[image]

```
    \documentclass{IEEEtran}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{afterpage}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    
    \newsavebox{\shortpagebox}
    \newsavebox{\shortpagefigure}
    \begin{document}
      \begin{figure*}
        \centering
        \setkeys{Gin}{width=0.48\linewidth} % <---
    \begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image}\hfil
    \includegraphics{example-image}
    
    \caption{fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff}
    \label{fig:first}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image}\hfil
    \includegraphics{example-image} 
    
    \caption{fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff}
    \label{fig:second}
    \end{minipage}
    
    \bigskip
    \begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image}\hfil
    \includegraphics{example-image}
    
    \caption{fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff}
    \label{fig:third}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image}\hfil
    \includegraphics{example-image}
    
    \caption{fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff}
    \label{fig:fourth}
    \end{minipage}
        \end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: have you tried using `\subcaption{...}` inside each `minipage`, and `\caption{...}` for the "overall" caption before \end{figure*}?

Comment: According to the IEEEtran manual: "However, most IEEE authors/journals do
not employ subfigure captions, but instead reference/describe
all of the subfigures (a), (b), etc., within the main caption."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you load the `subcaption` package, you could use its `subfigure` environment machinery -- a `subfigure` is, basically, a `minipage` environment that's been told what to do if it encounters a `\caption` directive in its scope -- to achieve your formatting objective.

Two comments:

- You'll get some warning messages as the `caption` and `subcaption` packages aren't fully aware of what the `IEEEtran` document class can and cannot do. You may ignore these warning messages.
- The output of the approach proposed here is quite similar to that of [Zarko's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/610814/5001), which isn't surprising as both answers employ the `subcaption` package. A possibly meaningful difference in the approaches may be that that using `subfigure` environments rather than `\subfloat` macros provides a touch more flexibility in terms of vertical positioning  of the graphs.

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[skip=0.33\baselineskip]{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{figure}{7} % just for this example

\begin{figure*}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\columnwidth}% 1st minipage
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.475\linewidth}%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{CNN with \dots}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.475\linewidth}%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{LTSM with \dots}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{The distribution of score}
\label{fig:first}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{\columnwidth}% 2nd minipage
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.475\linewidth}%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Rounds vs.\ accuracy}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.475\linewidth}%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image} 
    \caption{Payment $p$ and score with $N$}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Training speed and payment with parameter $N$}
\label{fig:second}
\end{minipage}
    
\bigskip\medskip
\begin{minipage}[t]{\columnwidth}% 3rd minipage
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.475\linewidth}%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Rounds vs.\ accuracy}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.475\linewidth}%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Payment $p$ and score with $K$}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Training speed and payment with parameter $K$}
\label{fig:third}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{\columnwidth}% 4th minipage
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.475\linewidth}%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Training speed with $p$}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.475\linewidth}%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image} 
    \caption{Proportion of selected node}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Performance impact of parameter $\psi$}
\label{fig:fourth}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you want to make it look like normal figures, use `\vskip\floatsep` between rows.

Comment: @JohnKormylo - Thanks. In my opinion, `\vskip\floatsep` doesn't insert quite enough whitespace for the material at hand -- at least not if the `IEEEtran` document class is in use. Of course, others may disagree. The skips `\floatsep`, `\bigskipamount`, and `\medskipamount` work out to `10.2pt plus 2.4pt minus 2.4pt`, `12pt plus 4pt minus 4pt`, and `6pt plus 2pt minus 2pt`.

Answer (score 7):

Each image insert in `\subfloat` environment (also defined in the `subcaption` package. In answer is assumed that all images in figure have equal which, which consequently can be defined by key `Gin` for all of them in figure.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
      \begin{figure*}
        \centering
        \setkeys{Gin}{width=0.48\linewidth} % <---
\begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
\subfloat[CNN with CIFAR-10]{\includegraphics{example-image}}\hfill
\subfloat[LSTM with HPNews]{ \includegraphics{example-image}}

    \caption{The distribution of score}
    \label{fig:first}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
\subfloat[caption 2a]{\includegraphics{example-image}}\hfill
\subfloat[caption 2b]{\includegraphics{example-image}}

    \caption{fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff}
\label{fig:second}
\end{minipage}

    \bigskip
\begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
\subfloat[caption 3a]{\includegraphics{example-image}}\hfill
\subfloat[caption 3b]{\includegraphics{example-image}}

\caption{fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff}
\label{fig:third}
\end{minipage}
    \hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
\subfloat[caption 4a]{\includegraphics{example-image}}\hfill
\subfloat[caption 4b]{\includegraphics{example-image}}

\caption{fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff}
\label{fig:fourth}
\end{minipage}
    \end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

[image]